# Facebook Android SDK 4.5 LikeView not working

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sdk-4.x

I am trying to integrate latest facebook android sdk(v 4.5) Like button. This is what I have put in my facebook_layout.xml

```
<com.facebook.share.widget.LikeView
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:id="@+id/like_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center">
</com.facebook.share.widget.LikeView>
```

And I have a fragment where I am putting this like view onCreate method to 
initialize the view

```
LikeView likeView = (LikeView)facebookview.findViewById(R.id.like_view);
likeView.setEnabled(true);
likeView.setLikeViewStyle(LikeView.Style.BOX_COUNT);
likeView.setObjectIdAndType(
"https://www.facebook.com/FacebookDevelopers",
LikeView.ObjectType.PAGE);
```

Apart from this I have also put my app id in AndroidManifest.xml as mentioned [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/android)

But I am still not able to get the like to work. When I Click on the like button it just opens up a black facebook activity and for few seconds and closes it, and there are no likes happening on this page or the same page i have created for testing.

Comment: Are you able to repro this on the latest SDK with one of the bundled samples? if so, have you tried different user accounts and devices?

Comment: I am using maven repository for the SDK dependency in gradle and 4.5 is the latest version there. I have tried it with bundled samples as well. And yes i have tried with multiple user accounts and with multiple devices- namely Nexus 5(v5.1.1) and MotoE(v 4.4.4) and Nexus 4(API 19) emulator.
I have also raised the issue on developer.facebook.com https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/125374871144350

Comment: I'm handling your bug report on Facebook side :), let's continue the discussion there and if this turned to be a bug you can post the bug after confirming the bug (if any)

Comment: I am also experiencing the same issue, did you @imgame get any workaround.

Answer (score 1):

I have resolved this issue by adding my facebook user as a Tester/Developer to my facebook android App.

Reference: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/security

Note: you can set the error listener to the object of LikeView for the better understanding of what error you are getting.

```
likeView.setOnErrorListener(new LikeView.OnErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    });
```